# Could not enter data: You have an error in your SQL syntax;

Tags: php, sql, mariadb

Can someone help me out from this problem? 
Here is my PHP code but I get stuck with the error:

> Could not enter data: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right
>   syntax to use near ')' at line 1

How to fix it?

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO pemohon2(p_id,k_nom_siri,p_jenis_aset,p_pengguna_terakhir,p_tarikh_rosak) SELECT P_ID,K_nom_siri,P_jenis_aset,P_pengguna_terakhir,P_tarikh_rosak FROM pemohon )";

mysql_select_db('kenderaan');
$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );

if(! $retval ) {
   die('Could not enter data: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_close($conn);
```

Comment: Please [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). [These extensions](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.removed-exts-sapis.php) have been removed in PHP 7. Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and consider using PDO, [it's really pretty easy](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysqli_connect() in..i got this error when use mysqli..why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, please use mysqli instead mysql as it is deprecated. For instance,

```
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");
```

Second, you are missing word "values" inside query.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO pemohon2 values(p_id,k_nom_siri,p_jenis_aset,p_pengguna_terakhir,p_tarikh_rosak) ;
```

lastly, your variable reference is not assign inside PHP. For instance,

```
$p_id=p_id;
$k_nom_siri=k_nom_siri;    

$sql = "INSERT INTO pemohon2($p_id,$k_nom_siri)";
```

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysqli_connect() in..i got this error when use mysqli..why?

Comment: looks like in you server mysqli extension is not enabled. check if mysqli is enabled phpinfo()

Comment: can you help me how to enable mysqli? sorry im really still new in php.. here code in my phpinfo.php
<?php
/* vim: set expandtab sw=4 ts=4 sts=4: */
/**
 * phpinfo() wrapper to allow displaying only when configured to do so.
 *
 * @package PhpMyAdmin
 */

/**
 * Gets core libraries and defines some variables
 */
require_once 'libraries/common.inc.php';
PMA_Response::getInstance()->disable();

/**
 * Displays PHP information
 */
if ($GLOBALS['cfg']['ShowPhpInfo']) {
    phpinfo();
}

Comment: what OS you are using?

Comment: windows..but thanks a lot because my problem already solve with your help :D thank you for helping me

Comment: okay, happy coding and welcome to PHP

Answer (score 1):

remove last ")" in your query

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO pemohon2(p_id,k_nom_siri,p_jenis_aset,p_pengguna_terakhir,p_tarikh_rosak) SELECT P_ID,K_nom_siri,P_jenis_aset,P_pengguna_terakhir,P_tarikh_rosak FROM pemohon";
```